# Delphi - ValueListEditor not adding new row

Tags: list, delphi, insert, ini

I have a procedure which needs to read data from an ini file with the following format:
`'Prices', [integer], [data to be read]`

The data read consists of two pieces of information split by a `'/'` symbol. The data is split successfully when I call my procedure below.

I have a `TValueListEditor` (called `ledtPrices`) placed on the form and would like to add the values from the ini file to the List Editor. If I call `ledtPrices.InsertRow` via a button click, the values I enter into to add to the row are added and the list editor is refreshed.

However, when I call the same function from my `RefreshPList` procedure, the values are not added as new rows (the list editor is blank). I have tested my code with `ShowMessage` dialogues to ensure each part of the procedure is functioning when it should. My code is as follows:

```
procedure RefreshPList;
var
  l: TValueListEditor;
  xFile: TINIFile;
  temprow, tl, tp: string;
  tempr: TStringList;
  i: integer;
begin
  i := 0;
  l := frmSettings.ledtPrices;
  try
    tempr := TStringList.Create;
    tempr.StrictDelimiter := True;
    tempr.Delimiter := '/';
  xFile := TIniFIle.Create('C:\MData.ini');
    try
    temprow := xFile.ReadString('Prices', '0', 'xx');
    if temprow = 'xx' then
      ShowMessage('no prices saved')
    else
    begin
    repeat
      temprow := xFile.ReadString('Prices', IntToStr(i), 'xx');
      if temprow <> 'xx' then
        begin
          tempr.DelimitedText := temprow;
          tl := tempr[0];
          tp := tempr[1];
          l.InsertRow(tl,tp,true);
          //ShowMessage(tl);
          Inc(i);
        end
      else
        ShowMessage('End of list');
    until (temprow = 'xx');
    //l.Refresh;
    end;
    finally
      xFile.Free;
    end;
    LastLine := i;
  finally
    tempr.Free;
  end;
end;
```

`LastLine` is a global integer value to be used later. I'm trying to add, remove and edit data within the list editor, without editing the cells directly. The procedure to add new data to the ini file has been written and runs successfully.

---

### UPDATE

I've come to realise that any procedure that I create which tries to edit a components values does not edit the components values. Am I missing something simple here?

For example, I created a memo on the form and created a procedure which adds the contents of an array to the memo.lines. This procedure did not execute when called from a buttonclick. However, if I copy the contents of the procedure directly into the buttonclick and execute it, it works.

The procedures are called from buttonclick commands. The form is created from a mainform. The components all sit within a pagecontrol tabsheet.

Comment: If the `tl` and `tp` were both empty strings (which may happen if the `temprow` will be just delimiter `/`), then the row won't be added. In other words, if you'd call `ValueListEditor.InsertRow('', '', True)`, no row would be added. Now it's the time to learn how to use debugger because I'm afraid we won't be able to trace it for you without knowing more...

Comment: Also how to use the code formatter :-)

Comment: @JerryDodge There's always space for learning.

Comment: @TLama I know how to use the debugger, but I used showmessage to check if `tl` and `tp` hold the values they should; and they do. Therefore, the insertrow() would not be blank. right?

Comment: @Babah254 Try it out, it formats your code to the most common standards, so you can learn how to keep your code logistically readable - Go to Edit > Format Source (If your Delphi version supports it) or do `CTRL + D`

Comment: @Babah254, so the line where the `InsertRow` is called executes ? And at least one of the mentioned variables contains a non-empty string value ? If so, then you are referencing a different component... You can always narrow down your problem if you remove all that file reading stuff and just manually try to assing a string to the `temprow` and let it insert a row into the value list.

Comment: @JerryDodge Thanks for that :) It does look neat. I think the only difference is that I tend to add an extra indent for all `begin` and `end` sections. I've come to realise that nobody else does this, but i've just conditioned myself to do it like that. The code above is a bad example. Cheers for the help

Comment: @TLama I'll run through the debugger now to ensure the function is executed.

Comment: @Babah254 You can also customize the way it formats, by going to Tools > Options > Environment Options > Formatter > Delphi > ...

Comment: @I'll have a mess around with it later. It looks like it'll come in handy to keep all my code the same format. Thanks again. More than happy to hear any more tips and tricks.

Comment: @TLama I just ran through the debugger. The `tp` and `tl` values are valid and are being pased to the InsertRow, which is being executed. I'm finding it too difficult to break down what appens to these values within the InsertRow function as the code and variable list become too confusing for me to break apart.

Comment: You're probably missing something simple.

Answer (score 0):

A quick test application (XE5, VCL Forms) cannot reproduce the problem.

I start with a new blank application, drop a `TValueListEditor` and a `TButton` on the form, and use the Object Inspector to add two key/value combinations:

```
Key      Value
---      -----
A        Aaaaaaa
C        Ccccccc
```

In the `TButton.OnClick` event, I use the following code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  NewKey, NewValue: string;
begin
  NewKey := 'B';
  NewValue := 'Bbbbbbb';
  ValueListEditor1.InsertRow(NewKey, NewValue, True);
end;
```

I run the application:

[image: Image of form with TValueList with two items]

I click `Button1`, and the code successfully adds the new item at the end (bottom) of the `TValueListEditor`.

[image: Image of form after clicking button and ValueListEditor with new item added]

I change the last parameter to `InsertRow` to `False`, and it inserts it at the start (top) of the `TValueListEditor`.

This indicates that either you're not getting the values you expect from your ini file, or the code that inserts the new row isn't executing.

Here's the full code of the test app I created:

Unit1.dfm

```
object Form4: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form4'
  ClientHeight = 178
  ClientWidth = 447
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object ValueListEditor1: TValueListEditor
    Left = 40
    Top = 16
    Width = 306
    Height = 137
    Strings.Strings = (
      'A=Aaaaaaa'
      'C=Ccccccc')
    TabOrder = 0
  end
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 352
    Top = 16
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Button1'
    TabOrder = 1
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
end
```

Unit1.pas

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Grids, Vcl.ValEdit;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ValueListEditor1: TValueListEditor;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  NewKey, NewValue: string;
begin
  NewKey := 'B';
  NewValue := 'Bbbbbbb';
  ValueListEditor1.InsertRow(NewKey, NewValue, True);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Thanks for doing that quick check. I decide to play around with an insert function with given parameters, within my code. What i did is copy and paste `InsertRow('hello','world',true)` into various sections of my refresh procedure. None of the lines were executed. I don't understand why this is happening, since I can execute the Insert function from a buttonclick and it functions perfectly well.

Comment: I can't help with that, because you've provided no details in your question about where `RefreshPList` is defined or how it's being called. The debugger should explain what's happening; set a breakpoint on the line of code that calls `RefreshPList` and then run your app, and step through the code to see where it goes and why it's not executing your added lines.

Comment: Read my last comment again. "I can't help with that, because **you've provided no details about where RefreshPList is defined or how it's being called. Set a breakpoint on the line of code that calls your procedure, run your app, and step through the code to see where it goes and why it's not executing your added lines of code.** We can't do that, because **we don't have the code you haven't shown us.** You do.